# Combining bind events without losing context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two event bindings on table rows, one for `focus` so I can get the value of a text input before it's changed. Then I bind the .change event to that, so I can handle it while still having the previous value.

But, in the .change function, "this" is now the table of the input being changed and no longer the input element itself. What am I doing wrong here?

```
(function() {
            var previousName;

            $(".RowClassName").on("focus", ".columnClassName td:first-child input", function() {
                previousName = this.value;
            }).change(function() {
                $(this).width($(this).val().length * 9);

                UpdateList(previousName, this.value);
            });
        })();
```

Comment: Bind the handler exactly how you bind the `focus` handler.

Comment: @SexyTurnip the rows are dynamically added, so wouldn't that not work?

Comment: @FelixKling So `$(".RowClassName").on("focus", ".columnClassName td:first-child input", function() {
                previousName = this.value;
            }).on("change", ".columnClassName td:first-child input", function()...` ? There's no way around having to rewrite the same selector each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `this` refers to the table was already explained in the other answers.

To avoid repeating the selector, you can either store in a variable or [pass an object](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) of event handlers:

```
(function() {
    var previousName;
    $(".RowClassName").on(
      {
         focus: function() { 
           previousName = this.value;
         },
         change: function() {
           $(this).width($(this).val().length * 9);
           UpdateList(previousName, this.value);
         }
      },
      '.columnClassName td:first-child input'
    );
}());
```

Comment: Would I have to move `previousName` to a global variable for this implementation?

Comment: No, you can do it as you do now. Why should it make a difference?

Comment: Gotcha! I edited your answer to include that, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".RowClassName").on("focus", ".columnClassName td:first-child input", ...)
```

^ This call resolves to the `.RowClassName` element, not the `input` element you use in the event delegation filter.

Try something like this:

```
var filter = ".columnClassName td:first-child input";

$(".RowClassName").on("focus", filter, function() {
    previousName = this.value;
}).on("change", filter, function() {
    $(this).width($(this).val().length * 9);
    UpdateList(previousName, this.value);
});
```

Comment: I see what you're saying in the first part, but that part is working and "this" after the focus is indeed the input element.

Comment: Right, because when you use event delegation (indicated by the extra selector/filter being passed to `.on(<event>, <filter>, <handler>)`, jQuery binds the handler to the element matching that filter (i.e., the `input` tag). However, the `.on()` function itself still follows normal chaining behavior and *returns* the same jQuery collection that it was called on (which is the collection matching the `.RowClassName` selector).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the `change` event to the row, not the input; you should try something like this:

```
var previousName = '';
$(".RowClassName").on("focus", ".columnClassName td:first-child input",    
   function() {
       previousName = this.value;
 })

$(".RowClassName").on("change", ".columnClassName td:first-child input",
   function() {
       $(this).width($(this).val().length * 9);
       UpdateList(previousName, this.value);
});
```